# Constructing HTML elements with readability and maintenance in mind

Tags: javascript, jquery

When iterating over some table cell data, I construct an array of whatever's found. The first iteration simply wraps the found text in some `<span>` tags, whilst the subsequent ones add a bunch of other styles, as below:

```
var array = $('table').find('th').map(function(i){
    if (i===0){
        // This bit's OK
        return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
    } else {
        // This just looks horrible
        return '<span style="width:' + $(this).outerWidth() + 'px; display:inline-block; position:absolute; right:' + w[i-1] + 'px">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
    }
}).get();
```

It all works fine, but it's hideous - and I think I've seen a much more elegant way of constructing HTML elements, with styles, somewhere before.

Can anyone suggest a more "maintenance-friendly" way of writing the `else` statement?

**EDIT**: Using CSS classes isn't really a solution, as the code applies values based on other calculations.

Comment: use classes and not inline css code

Comment: @andrew I guess that would reduce the code a bit, but the function also applies widths to the spans, depending on the width of the found data.

Comment: For the first iteration you could use jQuery's [`wrap` function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap your element in a `<span>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already suggested in the comments, consider storing the values that are used on all elements in a CSS class, I'll choose `.something`for this example.

```
.something {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Next, in the jQuery, you can store a copy of your span element in a variable as you're going to use it in both cases. In the `else` block you can then simply apply the class and add the individual styles.

**EDIT**: You can simplify the code even more. You'll return the span whatever happens so you only have to check if `i` is not equal to 0.

```
var array = $('table').find('th').map(function (i){
  var span = $('<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>');

  if (i !== 0) {
    span.addClass('something').css({
      width: $(this).outerWidth() + 'px',
      right: w[i-1] + 'px'
    });
  }

  return span;
}).get();
```

Comment: Much nicer - I'll give this a go.

Comment: Sadly, there's an issue: Uncaught TypeError: Object <span>TEXT</span> has no method 'css'

Comment: @verism My bad, you have to wrap the span variable in a jQuery object: `var span = $('<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>');

Comment: Almost... now I get [object Object] repeated for every array value. Sorry, I wish I knew more so I could debug this myself!

Comment: Those are your jQuery objects. Try it out by accessing `array[0].text()`, this should return the first span's text. If it doesn't work the way you want, you could provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example.

Comment: I just came across this solution: return span[0].outerHTML;

Comment: That depends on what you're after. The code I provided returns the `span` elements as jQuery objects while yours returns them as HTML strings.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - they're to be appended at a later stage, so strings were ideal in this case. But I understand why that wouldn't always be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about something more like this?

```
var array = $('table').find('th').map(function(i){

    var element = $("<span></span>").text($(this).text());
    return (i === 0) ? element : element.css({"width": $(this).outerWidth() + "px"
                                               , "display": "inline-block"
                                               , "position": "absolute"
                                               , "right": w[i-1] + "px"});

}).get();
```